# Computing distances in a river network for each node in Python(Arcpy)

Tags: python, network-programming, gis, arcpy, topology

I have a randomly created river network in ArcMap as Shapefile (Polyline). The goal is to calculate the distances from each node to the most distant source point and store them in a dictionary.

[River network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVNj6.png) (red = source points, black = confluence points, green = estuary point)

I have already saved the lengths of the individual polyline segments in a new field in the shapefile. These lengths are also stored in a new dictionary in Python. Each key has a corresponding length. The topology is stored in two more dictionaries. One dictionary contains the edge numbers as key and the start and end point of the edge in the value. The second dictionary contains all nodes as key and the  corresponding edges to each node as value.

```
length = {0:[10.25], 1:[9.58], 2:[11.99], 3:[9.50], 4:[26.28]}
edges = {0:[0,1], 1:[2,1], 2:[1,3], 3:[4,3], 4:[3,5]}
nodes = {0:[1], 1:[0], 2:[3], 3:[2,3,4], 4:[0,1,2], 5:[4]}
```

Moreover I have three lists with the source points, the estuary point and the confluence points respectively.

My problem is that I don't know how to use the given dictionaries to determine the distances of the nodes to the farthest source point. One consideration for my part is to save the distance planes from the point of intersection in another dictionary, but I don't know whether this helps or is necessary. This would look like this (Key = topology level, value = node):

```
dist = {0:[5], 1:[3], 2:[1,4], 3:[0,2]}
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks, Matthew

Comment: Maybe using NetworkX package can help you : https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/index.html
You can construct a graph with distance as weights and search for the maximum value for all path between your node and source point.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will try this out. The exercise I described is a homework, so with regard to the homework it would be better to solve it with normal python functions/arcpy.